# Typescript could NOT infer types correctly for a new type that unions two object types

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, union-types

I defined a type that unions an object type and a record type like this. But when I use the new type, I found the types that TS inferred are not the same as those I wish:

```js
type myType = {"204": {}} | Record<string, Record<string, number>>;
const foo = (param: myType) => {
  Object.keys(param).forEach(code => {
    if(code === "204") {
      const emptyRes = param[code]
    } else {
      const res = param[code] // error No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'myType'
    }
  })
}
```

what I want to get is `const emptyRes: {}` and `const res: Record<string, Record<string, number>>`

But I got `const emptyRes: {} | Record<string, number>` and an error on `res`. they are both not the same as I expected.

Here's the minimal reproducible [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAtiAq5oF4oG8BEAmADAFgwC50BfEqAHygCUIBjAewCcATAHgGdgmBLAOwDmAGhr1m7Lr0Ei%20AVxgAjCEwB8KgNwAoRny5QAZgwZRUACjABDJhZjE4iSAEoTK9JqhQA8goBW9YAB0ANYQIBzmVjaOAYZMAKIWdAAWpowsKK5o7h5QPPqpDOkmyKjY%20BjOWTk5OnoQMGCgtBwmUJbWMADaaRAAulAA9ANQtcBQ9Y0gzcRo5FS0jKyc3PzCUHKKyirZHuQQADYc0FXVIwy6Y0wQLajtNt2FfYPDykzMUAByxvzpAB5QHB4Aj4FmAsiuUAA7jxgEkoBY2pEYBBgMooAx9FBQJAoABySSrXFQiwtQyyPgsdF8LFIPH2JC4nZQEjZEiOTQkIA)

Comment: I get `Record<string, number>` in both cases: https://tsplay.dev/mLqQkW

Comment: it seems that it depends on what the object a real is.
`a: t = {"204": {}}` will get the result I mentioned above, but `a: t = {}` will get both `Record<string, number>`
But in my circumstance, TS compiler won't know what the object really is, I just keep the two types at the same time.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue you're seeing. Also, please explain exactly why you expect your desired results; if I have a *union* of two  types then indexing into it will either give you a union (if the key is known to exist in both types) or an indexing error (if the key is not known to exist in both types).  Perhaps you meant for `t` to be an *intersection* instead? We need clarification from you about exactly what you are doing and what your use case is before a suggestion can be made. Finally, make sure to ask an explicit question in your post.

Comment: You safely cannot use the key `"204"` to narrow a value of type `MyType`, nor does the fact that the key is *not* `"204"` imply that the value type is a `Record<string, number>`.  See [this example](https://tsplay.dev/mAKp4w).  The type `{}` is very loose so it's hard for me to understand your use case.  But if you want to write a type guard function to tell the compiler that the presence `204` distinguishes things, then you can do so like [this](//tsplay.dev/mpnqXw).  Do you want me to write up an answer or am I missing something? (Please @jcalz mention me if you reply or I won't be notified)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your patience. I just want to write a type guard function to tell the compiler that the presence `204` distinguishes other keys. Now I've solved my problem with your example.